# Combining vectors of string's

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a number of vectors of strings each containing dates. As a simple example vector A 
of size 2 might contain:

```
A[0] = "01-Jul-2010"; 
A[1] = "03-Jul-2010";
```

while a second vector B of size 3 might contain:

```
B[0] = "02-Jul-2010";
B[1] = "03-Jul-2010"; 
B[2] = "04-Jul-2010";
```

I'd like to form a vector C which contains the 'union' of the element in A and B:

```
C[0] = "01-Jul-2010";
C[1] = "02-Jul-2010";
C[2] = "03-Jul-2010";
C[3] = "04-Jul-2010";
```

When combining A and B I don't want any repeated dates so each element of C must be unique. Is there any in-built/stl (or Boost library) function I can call that 
will do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I assumed from your last paragraph this is a C++ question, so I have tagged it as such.  It also doesn't seem to be related to dates, so I removed that tag.

Comment: Thats correct it's a C++ question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If set is not applicable std::unique is also possible:

```
   std::vector<std::string> A;
   std::vector<std::string> B;
   std::vector<std::string> C;

   A.resize (2u);
   B.resize (3u);

   A[0] = "01-Jul-2010";  
   A[1] = "03-Jul-2010"; 

   B[0] = "02-Jul-2010"; 
   B[1] = "03-Jul-2010";  
   B[2] = "04-Jul-2010";   

   C.reserve (5u);

   std::copy (
      A.begin (),
      A.end (),
      std::back_inserter (C)
      );

   std::copy (
      B.begin (),
      B.end (),
      std::back_inserter (C)
      );

   // std::unique requires sorted vector
   std::sort (C.begin(), C.end());
   C.erase (
      std::unique (C.begin(), C.end()),
      C.end ()
      );
```

Answer (score 5):

There is [a  `set_union`  function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/) in STL to find the union of two (lexicographically) sorted sequences. Assuming A and B are already sorted,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

...

std::vector<std::string> C;
std::set_union(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(), std::back_inserter(C));
```

---

If A and B are sorted by date, you need to supply that date-comparing function / functor, e.g.

```
bool is_earlier(const std::string& first_date, const std::string& second_date) {
   // return whether first_date is earlier than second_date.
}

...

std::set_union(A.begin(), A.end(), B.begin(), B.end(),
               std::back_inserter(C), is_earlier);
```

Comment: Note that _sorted_ in this case means _lexically sorted_, not sorted by date (so, "01-Aug-2010" would come before "02-Jul-2010").

Comment: @James: If it is sorted by date, we could supply the 6th parameter.

Comment: I take it that, by "6th parameter", you mean a comparison function or functor?  It might be well to put this into your answer in more detail, because I think we may be losing Wawel100 at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set (but not a multiset) as an (intermediate) container instead of a vector.  This strips any ordering you may want to keep, though.

You can also use `std::unique`, `std::remove_if`, or [`std::set_union`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set_union.html) (assuming the inputs are sorted).

Comment: The dates will need to be in order.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an [STL set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/). That'll ensure that you don't have duplicates.